# Make element resizable in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make div vertically resizable using Angular 2+.
It should works like this: if user mousedown on resizer element and move cursor up/down and then mouseup - the div should have appropriate height.

```
<div #resizable class="resizable">
  <div class="resizer">RESIZE</div>
</div>



export class AppComponent {
  public resizable: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('resizable') set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if(content) {
      this.resizable = content;
      this.resizable.nativeElement.addEventListener('mousedown', this.resizeMouseDown.bind(this))
      this.resizable.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.resizeMouseUp.bind(this))
    }
  }

  public resizeMouseDown() {

  }

  public resizeMouseUp() {
    
  }
}
```

I think it should be done by adding and removing event handlers (mousedown, mouseup, mousemove) in specific situation.
Could anyone help me, please?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-h19bwy?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: `nativeElement.addEventListener('mousedown')`?? And in an Angular project, what about using... Angular stuff? Like `(click)="resizeMouseDown()"` ?

Comment: @Lukasz, I mark your question as duplicate. Note: if you want to look for the questions you has made, you can see in your profile (the "button" to right search input and to the left "Recent inbox message" icon)